# Android - can I direct midi output of MediaPlayer to Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth, midi

I am new to Android development, and would like to know if it is possible to send a midi file data out of Bluetooth?

I am using the following to load and start a midi file..

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

String music = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(music + "/test.mid"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

After requesting permissions etc, this will start playing the midi file on my device.

My next step it to send this out via Bluetooth, i.e. I want just the midi going to blue tooth and NOT any other audio that may be playing on my device (in another application).

How can this be done (if it can be done)?

### Edit 1

Just a bit more info that may have not been clear.

What I am after is sending midi data, NOT midi audio. Ie I want to load a midi file, and then send via Bluetooth to a Bluetooth midi cable like [this](https://koalaaudio.com.au/products/cme-pro-widi-master-wireless-midi-via-bluetooth?variant=39724575719493&currency=AUD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2020-08-08&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=Cj0KCQjwr-SSBhC9ARIsANhzu15Xl86bTNvW7MSwJYfcmXf97odmYhcqjEdY9yI1FZA1TvOOmSEKBkUaAqsEEALw_wcB), which is plugged into a keyboard, and have the midi file play the keyboard.

Comment: Call setPreferredDevice with the parameter for the device you want, probably   TYPE_BLE_HEADSET

Comment: Thank you, looks promising, I will check it out.

Comment: I am now not sure MediaPlayer will do what I am after (extended my post to make it a bit more clear) - perhaps I'll do a new post just on this part

Comment: Have an associated post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890266/android-how-to-play-a-midi-file-data-to-external-midi-keyboard)

Comment: Ok, so what you want would be to not use MediaPlayer at all.  MediaPlayer is for playing music.  If you want to send data to a device that's a totally different thing.